# After calling SubmitForm, how can I retrieve what I submitted?

Tags: forms, form-submit, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

`SubmitForm` has many benefits over `Patch`, such as triggering error messages in the form. However, I find that I often have to use `Patch` because `Patch` returns useful info on what was submitted, such as the ID of the row in the SharePoint List that the call to `Patch` has populated.

After calling `SubmitForm`, is there any way to retrieve what was submitted? In particular, I'm interesting in grabbing the SharePoint List's corresponding row ID .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use your Form.LastSubmit.*
Then you'll be able to retrieve data from last submitted item.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. You might want to link to the documentation or point out some key features like where that property can be accessed and give an example of how it can replace what I've said that I like about `Patch`.

Comment: Actually, this one could help.
https://www.spguides.com/powerapps-lastsubmit/